# problems with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.1.1' in the gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

This is my dependencies file and there is an underlined red colored text on the  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.1.1'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.mcaproject"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This because of this I am having problems changing themes in the styles.xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you hover over the red line it may show you the image like this which I have attached below.[image: Click to see the image]

What it tells you is there is a conflict of the version in some libraries so it suggests us to add those. For my case first, it showed for CardView and then for Design. So I added to it. Below is the code for it.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

so kindly add those it may be 2 or more than that.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This trick worked like a charm But had to remove com.payumoney,

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.0 ,the **compile** configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by implementation or api.

Just replace:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.1.1'`

- **compile** with **implementation**
- **testCompile** with **testImplementation**.
- **debugCompile** with **debugImplementation**.
- **androidTestCompile** with **androidTestImplementation**.
- **compileOnly** is still valid. It was added in 3.0 to replace provided and not compile.

for more information read this [gradel doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason of fail

You are using incompatible version of firebase with 27.1.1 support version.

Current version > `16.0.0` and you use `11.6.0`.

#### Solution

Update your firebase dependencies versions. I suggest update target sdk version also.

Below is updated gradle as of date 1-10-2018, you can see [firebase page](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) to check latest version.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.mcaproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

#### Suggestion

Migrate to [`androidx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563) because Android will not update support libraries after version 28.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

just goto-> files->project structures->app->flavors
change your min SDK version and target SDK version  to "API 27:" 
then go to properties and check that your compile SDK version has also changed to the above version which you selected.

This worked for me.