# Gradle 3 `compile project` and `compile files` deprecated?

Tags: android

How would I translate those to `implementation` or `api`?

Fx. what should I replace those with?

```
compile project(':jabraServiceApi')
compile files('libs/samsung-digital-health-healthdata-1.2.1.jar')
```

Maybe `compile project` and `compile files` are still supported and should stay as they are?

Comment: `implementation project` is correct https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#variant_dependencies

Comment: implementation project(':jabraServiceApi') worked for me.use Gradle 4.4 and build tool 3.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle 3.4 introduced new  [Java Library plugin configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) configurations that allow you to control whether a dependency is published to the compile and runtime classpaths of projects that consume that library. The Android plugin is adopting these new dependency configurations, and migrating large projects to use them can drastically reduce build times. The following table helps you understand which configurations you should use.
I already give the answer here please check [compile configuration is now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134403/4694074)  .

Comment: Note: This is not helpful for project and files as it does not explicitly state how to implement the new system for files and projects. `implementation project` is correct. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#variant_dependencies