# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.; for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ybalakrishn5\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Configuration 'compile' in project ':' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_3qixex8fyoiyv6i06dfwz0p62.run(C:\dev\cups\CUPS\platforms\android\build.gradle:144)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\dev\cups\CUPS\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 260
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\dev\cups\CUPS\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 260
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

[image]

Answer (score 1):

open your build.gradle inside the app folder and replace all the 'compile' to 'implementation' and 'testCompile' to 'testImplementation' and 'androidTestCompile' to 'androidTestImplementation'  for more info check this "[problems with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.1.1' in the gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134196/problems-with-com-android-supportappcompat-v7-27-1-1-in-the-gradle-file/50134403#50134403)"